# C++ Bitmap Library sample code not working

Tags: c++, eclipse, bitmap

I have added [this library](http://www.partow.net/programming/bitmap/index.html#simpleexample01) to my `src` folder in Eclipse, and put the demo code in my `Bitmap.cpp` `int main`. However, I am getting this error message:

```
Error - Failed to open: Color.bmp
bitmap_image::load_bitmap() ERROR: bitmap_image - Invalid type value 0 expected 19778.
```

Looking through the code, this is where the error comes from:

```cpp
bitmap_file_header bfh;
bitmap_information_header bih;

bfh.clear();
bih.clear();

read_bfh(stream, bfh);
read_bih(stream, bih);

if (bfh.type != 19778) {
  bfh.clear();
  bih.clear();

  stream.close();

  std::cerr
      << "bitmap_image::load_bitmap() ERROR: bitmap_image - Invalid type value "
      << bfh.type << " expected 19778." << std::endl;
  return;
}
```

Can someone help me in this issue?

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: We aren't the help desk to every sinlge project out there, this should go on their forums.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got the answer. The file extension was 'bmp' but the data was encoded as PNG:

[image: Answer]

Answer (score 0):

I use the same library but with some own additions. Anyway, you need some correction with the size of your input image. I use it for images 800x400p and it works perfectly. If you want to work with all sizes of bmp images, you need just other settings.

Comment: You need the number in hexadecimal and consult an ASCII table

Comment: I've tried to resize my bmps down to 800x400 and I am receiving an error that the BIH size is invalid, with size 124 and expecting 40...